# I just noticed I can't answer a question, but theres no notice about a reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users

I wanted to answer this question: [Why do RPGs let you know how much XP you need to level up?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167538/why-do-rpgs-let-you-know-how-much-xp-you-need-to-level-up) .

I suspect it's protected or closed or something like that, but there is no notice about that, like it would be on other stacks. Is this intended, and if so... why?

[image]

Top of the page:
[image]

Comment: The question is protected; I assume you don't see the message box below the author's name, above the comments?

Comment: Yes, I can not see the answerbox. My frustration/question is why it doesn't give me feedback that I can't answer because the question is protected, like it would do on other stackexchange sites. I added a screenshot to show where it would usually be.

Comment: Huh, yeah, your latest screenshot of the top of the page is surprising, I would have expected the banner there. :(

Answer (score 2):

The question you're asking about is [protected](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/), which means it cannot be answered by users who have less than 10 reputation on the site. The 100-point association bonus doesn't count, so as of right now you'd need to earn 9 reputation on the Game Development site

Questions are generally protected when they become popular and as a result start to attract low-quality responses (such as commentary posted as answers or spam).

The protection banner is displayed underneath the *question*:

[image]

It's arguable that it should also be displayed in some form by the answer box. It certainly seems like it would be useful for questions with a long answer list. But I don't think other SE sites do that? If I'm wrong, that's unfortunately not something we can fix without SE's intervention.

Comment: I assumed that was the case, but it didn't show the usual notification for it. I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @Lichtbringer Your screenshot shows the bottom of the page; the notice is usually underneath the question, not near the answer box. Do you also not see the notice under the question, as in my screenshot above? Can you add a screenshot of another SE site showing you the notice in the answer box?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [Protection banner missing when I don't have enough rep to answer; closed and locked banners appear in wrong spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322971/protection-banner-missing-when-i-dont-have-enough-rep-to-answer-closed-and-loc), so it seems it's not specific to this stack, but a sidewide problem.

It seems the intended behaviour is to show protected at the bottom where the answerbox is to user that have not enough rep, and show it at the top to users who have enough rep.
For some reason, it doesn't show at all.